# iOS 6 navigation bar is under status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

So im writing an app that needs to support ios 6 and 7, app looks good in iOS 7 but on iOS 6 for some reason the navigation bar sits underneath the status bar and i have no idea why. it happens on all of my screens

[image]

i've tried settings the status bar to opaque but everything i have tried still leaves it as translucent, i thought maybe having it opaque would make it move down (i would prefer to keep it translucent though)

running Xcode 5.1.1

i have my own navigation controller implemented, but all it does is set `self.navigationBar.tintColor = THEME_COLOUR;` (and some other things when in iOS 7 but that doesnt execute here)

in the storyboard i have unticked 'under top bars' and ive messed around with the UINavigation bar appearance property and nothing seems to affect it

Comment: You need to adjust the iOS6/7 deltas in your storyboard (right panel, size inspector, set 20 for DeltaY)

Comment: i dont seem to get the delta adjustments settings when i click on the viewcontroller's view and look under the size inspector, i only get auto layout stuff (which i am using)

Comment: if i click on the actual view controller it just has an option for simulated size, which is set to fixed at the moment

Comment: You need to select the specific view that is misplaced and handle the deltas on a per-view basis.

Comment: yeah i would, but with auto-layouts enabled ive read now that iOS 6/7 delta's are disabled, so i dont have that option to use delta's

Comment: Oh right.. I've disabled autolayout on all my non-iOS7-only projects so I'm not sure how to help you, sorry..

Comment: it looks like its to do with the plist file entry `status bar is initially hidden` when its set to YES i have the problem, when its NO i dont, but the status bar then shows up in the splash screen which is undesirable, so i wonder what i can do other than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So im not sure why, but i fixed the problem by manually moving the navigation bar down in my root view controller like so:

```
if( ! IS_OS_7_OR_LATER){

    CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    navFrame.origin.y += 20;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = navFrame;
}
```

it seems to be something to do with my login view having a hidden nav bar, then my root view unhiding the nav bar, but im not sure exactly what. but luckily i only needed that code in the root view and it seemed to affect all subsequent views (probably because the status bar and nav bar are inferred in the storyboard)

Comment: If you use storyboards, you can do it by selecting your view, going to the Size Inspector, and set the "iOS 6/7 Deltas" appropriately. No need to add any code !

Comment: not if you are using autolayouts, as per the discussion in the questions comments

Comment: Oh, right.. I did not see these comments.. Sorry for the useless comment then :)